# Applescript - Take a plain text and turn into a html link

Tags: mac, applescript

We work with bugzilla.  Whenever you need to query a ticket you just need to know the bugid (integer) and you simply prepend this to it.

```
http://<bugzilla_server>/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=<bug_id>
```

Suppose I have a bug link which looks like this [777](http://bugzilla_server/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=bug_id).  If I select and copy this it is preserved on the pasteboard so when I paste this into mail it will correctly preserve the link and it's attributes.

What I am looking for is to simple type '777' select it and run an applescript on it and replace it with a link like the one above.  Can anyone help me out??

Thanks

Comment: Better suited for StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850726/applescript-to-take-text-and-turn-it-into-pasteable-html